# How do I print out a long BIGINT in Yii in PHP?

Tags: php, yii2

When I print a BIGINT in Yii, it is rounding to MAX_INT. How do I print longs in Yii?

```
  foreach ($negativeKeywords as $i=>$v) {
    echo "$i: Removing $v->id, $v->campaign_id, $v->keyword, $v->google_id\n"; 

# 11: Removing 103, 2, gamtech, 2147483647
```

Real values:

```
=> select * from negative_keyword where id in (103,413);
 id  | campaign_id |  keyword   | match_type | status |  google_id  | bing_id
-----+-------------+------------+------------+--------+-------------+---------
 103 |           2 | gamtech    |          3 |      0 | 31883722149 |


=> \d negative_keyword;
   Column    |          Type          |                           Modifiers 
...
 google_id   | bigint                 |
```

Here is the migration which created the table

```
  $this->createTable('negative_keyword', [
    'id' => Schema::TYPE_PK,
    'google_id' => Schema::TYPE_BIGINT,
    ...
```

PHP 5.6.12 (cli) (built: Aug 11 2015 13:13:58)

Comment: It (a `google_id` column) must be a string type at a very first place.

Comment: Yeah it must be of a Varchar type but you can convert it to any type while retrieving through SELECT Query...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you need to convert the BIGINT to a VARCHR in Postgres.

`$accounts = Account::find()->select(['*', 'google_id' => 'cast(google_id as varchar)'])->all();`

The 'number' rule by itself doesn't always work (esp. Postgres 9.4).

Answer (score 1):

Try this : You need to add max value of Bigint.

```
public function rules(){
    return [
        [['number_min'],'number','min'=>10],
        [['number_max'],'number','max'=>100],
        [['number_min_max'],'number','min'=>10,'max'=>100],
    ];
}
```

Comment: Wow this was kind of right. I changed the rule from `integer` to add rule `[['google_id', 'bing_id'], 'number'],` and it worked. I didn't need to set `max`. I don't know why Gii generates the code that way with `integer`.

Comment: Sometimes that doesn't even work! I had to use this to convert the BIGINT to VARCHR: `$accounts = Account::find()->select(['*', 'google_id' => 'cast(google_id as varchar)'])->all();`

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it to string while retrieving data through Query:

**MYSQL**

```
SELECT CONVERT(google_id, CHAR(10))
FROM negative_keyword;
```

Increase CHAR length accordingly...

For more info check this [Reference](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/convert.php)

**PostgreSQL**

By Using `to_char()`, you can convert it into String in PostgreSQL

```
to_char(int, text)
```

For more info check this [Reference](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-formatting.html)

Comment: The database is Postgres. That way doesn't work very well with Yii though.